# how to set android default title bar at Bottom with image on it?

Tags: android

how to set android default title bar at Bottom with image on it ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible, because I never saw something like this. But I would suggest to hide the default title bar and the make your own title bar which can be displayed at the bottom. That shouldn't be too difficult.